# Changing a variable using SET GLOBAL doesn't impacts sessions variable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am bit confused between setting the global and session parameters , I am trying to set `wait_timeout`

The default settings are

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                 28800 |                  28800 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The below SQL will change the session setting

```
SET wait_timeout = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Check the values , which is pretty clear as well

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                 28800 |                     10 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The below SQL will change it globally

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Check the values , which is pretty clear as well

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                    10 |                     10 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Now , I am closing the MySQL thread and opening a new one , I find the below data**

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                    10 |                  28800 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not able to relate at this point why the session settings have been changed as I already changed the value using SET GLOBAL.

Comment: Session variable values are established at 'connection' event.  Running processes are not impacted in any way by SET GLOBAL gvn=value.  New 'connect' events/processes will pick up the current GLOBAL VALUE for the duration of the session connection.  You can within your query SET SESSION vn=value and additional processes in the query will have your requested value.  This is how you can make that 'long running' task be acceptable for 5 minutes when you might have a typical 60 second limit.

Answer (score 8):

In order to change `wait_timeout` we should also change `interactive_timeout` variables.

The definition of `wait_timeout` : The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it. On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout value.

**Here is the test**

Query without changing any parameter , all the values are set to 8 hours by default

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout , @@global.interactive_timeout , @@session.interactive_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout | @@global.interactive_timeout | @@session.interactive_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                 28800 |                  28800 |                        28800 |                         28800 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Change the parameter at session level

```
SET wait_timeout = 10 , interactive_timeout = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Results , all looks good as expected , global setting stay same and session settings are changed

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout , @@global.interactive_timeout , @@session.interactive_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout | @@global.interactive_timeout | @@session.interactive_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                 28800 |                     10 |                        28800 |                            10 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Change the parameter at global level

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 10 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Results , all looks good as expected

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout , @@global.interactive_timeout , @@session.interactive_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout | @@global.interactive_timeout | @@session.interactive_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                    10 |                     10 |                           10 |                            10 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Disconnect MySQL thread and connect again , and all looks good again

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout , @@global.interactive_timeout , @@session.interactive_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout | @@global.interactive_timeout | @@session.interactive_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                    10 |                     10 |                           10 |                            10 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you do not change your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section, after your next shutdown/crash restart, you will be back to the defaults mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`wait_timeout` is somewhat abnormal since it has two variants -- batch and interactive.

Others come in two flavors:  Just a global, which is immediately reflected in the session, versus globals that are copied into the session *when you connect*.  Which is which?  It seems to be a closely guarded secret that is best discovered by experimentation.

Comment: There are two global variables wait_timeout and interactive_timeout.  You may wish to think of interactive_timeout as batch since it seems to be in charge of timeout when you SSH into MySQL for command line processing activities inactivity tolerance.